# How to detect cause of Dart VM crash

Tags: amazon-web-services, dart

I have two Dart apps running on Amazon (AWS Ubuntu), which are:

1. Self-hosted http API
2. Worker that handles background tasks on a timer

Both apps use PostgreSQL. They were occasionally crashing so, in addition to trying to find the root causes, I also implemented a supervisor script that just detects whether those 2 main apps are running and restarts them as needed.

Now the problem I need to solve is that the supervisor script is crashing, or the VM is crashing. It happens every few days.

I don't think it is a memory leak because if I increase the polling rate from 10s to much more often (1 ns), it correctly shows in the Dart Observatory that it exhausts 30MB and then garbage-collects and starts over at low memory usage, and keeps cycling.

I don't *think* it's an uncaught exception because the infinite loop is completely enclosed in try/catch.

I'm at a loss for what else to try. Is there a VM dump file that can be examined if the VM really crashed? Is there any other technique to debug the root cause? Is Dart just not stable enough to run apps for days at a time?

This is the main part of the code in the supervisor script:

```
 ///never ending function checks the state of the other processes
 Future pulse() async {
   while (true) {
     sleep(new Duration(milliseconds: 100)); //DEBUG - was seconds:10
     try {
       //detect restart (as signaled from existence of restart.txt)
       File f_restart = new File('restart.txt');
       if (await f_restart.exists()) {
         log("supervisor: restart detected");
         await f_restart.delete();
         await endBoth();
         sleep(new Duration(seconds: 10));
       }

       //if restarting or either proc crashed, restart it
       bool apiAlive = await isRunning('api_alive.txt', 3);
       if (!apiAlive) await startApi();
       bool workerAlive = await isRunning('worker_alive.txt', 8);
       if (!workerAlive) await startWorker();

       //if it's time to send mail, run that process
       if (utcNow().isAfter(_nextMailUtc)) {
         log("supervisor: starting sendmail");
         Process.start('dart', [rootPath() + '/sendmail.dart'], workingDirectory: rootPath());
         _nextMailUtc = utcNow().add(_mailInterval);
       }

     } catch (ex) {}
   }
 }
```

Comment: You don't get any console output that contains information about the crash? Can you reproduce outside AWS (in a shell on your local machine)?

Comment: I tried running locally with vastly increased timing to reproduce, but could not. The supervisor script is writing stdout to a file, and that file doesn't have anything in it beyond what I'm writing explicitly. It's as if it just exits normally.

Comment: I assume you did redirect stderr to the file as well?

Comment: The problem with being a long-time Windows programmer is we forget stderr exists! Thanks Günter; that tip along with getting the dump from the observatory will help crack this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the observatory up you can get a crash dump with: 
`curl localhost:<your obseratory port>/_getCrashDump`

I'm not totally sure if this is related but `Process.start` returns a future which I don't believe will be caught by your try/catch if it completes with an error...

Comment: Process.start should be called (in my case) in detached mode; doing that seems to have made it more stable (but haven't figured out why). I'll try the observatory thing - thanks!